# Adding two variables containing integer values

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have fetched integer data in two variables from different tables. I need to apply the add operation so that I can get the sum of the values in those variables. I am a beginner though so please try to help me out here. I tried the code in Model and the result I am getting is : Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to int

```
$fromrequest = $this->db->query("SELECT Requests.sunit FROM Requests WHERE Requests.sid = 2");
$fromstock = $this->db->query("SELECT Stock.sunit FROM 
Stock WHERE Stock.ssid = 5");

$sum = $fromrequest + $fromstock
```

Answer (score 1):

first your queries are not definite. Look at "SELECT Requests.sunit FROM Requests", the query is going to list all Sunits in the table Requests. But you want to count or sum the sunit and assign them to the valuable $fromrequest  the query like

$fromrequest = $this->db->query("SELECT count(Requests.sunit) as Units FROM Requests");

or 
$fromrequest = $this->db->query("SELECT sum(Requests.sunit) as Units FROM Requests");

would results into an integer which would make your life easy. Try it and we see what we get. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made the changes in the query kindly go through it again. Now could you please tell me the solution according to the queries provided

Comment: **Sanyam** Please execute the your code again and share the error message if any, It's not like am having the same db or data on my side

Answer (score 1):

check the values and better use active record..

```
$get_fromrequest = $this->db->select('sunit')->where('sid',2)->get("Requests");
$fromrequest = $get_fromrequest->row();
if(isset($fromrequest)){
 $freq = $fromrequest->sunit;
} else {
 $freq = 0;
}
$get_fromstock = $this->db->select('sunit')->where('ssid',2)->get("Stock");
$fromstock = $get_fromstock->row();
if(isset($fromstock)){
  $fstock = $fromstock->sunit;
} else {
 $fstock = 0;
}
```

chang it

```
$sum = $fromrequest + $fromstock
```

to

```
$sum = abs($fromrequest) + abs($fromstock);
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but I am getting this error while using your code Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int. I am returning the $sum to controller using return $sum; and in controller a variable will hold the value returned from Model. Then I echo it but getting the error.

Comment: Finally got the answer mate. Thanks for your great help. I was not getting the answer by your codes because it should be $sum = abs($freq)+abs(fstock); Thanks and take care